# BigQuery: Aggregate multiple fields into array

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some data where for each ID I want to aggregate two or more fields into an array, and I want them to match in terms of order.

So for example if I have the following data:

[image]

I want to turn it into this:

[image]

Alternatively, something like this would also be fine:

[image]

So firstly, if I were to use a query like this, would it do what I want or does it not guarantee that the two fields pull through in the same order (i.e. that the corresponding values in Value_1 and Value_2 may not match)?

```
SELECT
  ID,
  ARRAY_AGG (
    Value_1
  ) AS Value_1,
  ARRAY_AGG (
    Value_2
  ) AS Value_2

FROM
  table

GROUP BY
  ID
```

If not, how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `ARRAY_AGG` with `STRUCT` if you want to pair the values together. For example,

```sql
SELECT
  ID,
  ARRAY_AGG (
    STRUCT(Value_1, Value_2)
  ) AS Values
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  ID;
```

Comment: This is awesome...exactly what i need for a truly denormalized table

Answer (score 7):

... and for your `alternative` ask:

```sql
SELECT  
  id,
  ARRAY_AGG(CONCAT('[', Value_1, ',', Value_2, ']')) AS Values
FROM `yourTable`
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: This generates a string instead of a list as concat returns a string. Is this also possible as list in list?

Comment: This is susceptible to SQL injection security vulnerability... Are we in '90s again?

Answer (score -1):

Working solution of `Array_Agg ()` with Python BigQuery:

```
!pip install -U google-cloud-bigquery
import pandas as pd

from google.cloud import bigquery

strvalue = """SELECT users ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(session, page )) as hasComp FROM <datasetname>.<tableName> WHERE Group by users order by users limit 100 """

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project="")

dataset = bigquery_client.dataset("")

table = dataset.table('')

table.view_query_legacy_sql = False

query_job = bigquery_client.query(str_value)

df = query_job.to_dataframe()

print(df)
```