# How to merge different schemas of structs in arrays (filling missing columns with null)?

Tags: google-bigquery

Given these one tables (`a` being an array of structs).

`baz_v1` (`a` being `ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64>>`):

```
+===========+
| a.x | b   |
+===========+
| 1   | one |
| 2   |     |
+===========+
```

`baz_v2` (`a` being `ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y INT64>>`):

```
+=================+
| a.x | a.z | b   |
+=================+
| 3   | 4   | one |
| 5   | 6   |     |
+-----------------+
| 7   | 8   | two |
| 9   | 0   |     |
+-----------------+
| 11  | 12  | two |
| 13  | 14  |     |
+=================+
```

How can I obtain the following (concatenated) table/view?

```
+==================+
| a.x | a.y  | b   |
+==================+
| 1   | null | one |
| 2   | null |     |
+------------------+
| 3   | 4    | one |
| 5   | 6    |     |
+------------------+
| 7   | 8    | two |
| 9   | 10   |     |
+------------------+
| 11  | 12   | two |
| 13  | 14   |     |
+==================+
```

Code:

```sql
WITH `baz_v1` AS (
    SELECT
    [
        STRUCT(1 AS x),
        STRUCT(2 AS x)
    ]
    a,
    "one" b
), `baz_v2` AS (
    SELECT
    [
        STRUCT(3 AS x, 4 AS y),
        STRUCT(5 AS x, 6 AS y)
    ]
    a,
    "one" b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    [
        STRUCT(7 AS x, 8 AS y),
        STRUCT(9 AS x, 10 AS y)
    ]
    a,
    "two" b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    [
        STRUCT(11 AS x, 12 AS y),
        STRUCT(13 AS x, 14 AS y)
    ]
    a,
    "two" b
)

-- todo: Insert magic here, because the below, of course, does not work.
SELECT * FROM baz_v2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM baz_v1
```

Comment: a. can you have same value for `b` in both tables? b. can you have same value for 'b' in multiple rows of same table? c. if yes of a. or b. how to concatenate those?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thanks for the very good questions. I've just edited my post to answer them.

Comment: so i read it as - yes for a. and no for b. - correct? (a. and b. are questions in my above comments)

Comment: a) Yes, we can have the same value for `b` in both tables. b) Yes, we can have the same value for `b` in multiple rows of the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
select * replace(
  array(select as struct x, null as y from t.a) as a)
from `baz_v1` t
union all 
select * from `baz_v2`
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69817220/1866775) given by [Mikhail Berlyant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/), I've found another solution, one that does not use `SELECT * REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT x, NULL AS y FROM baz_v1.a) AS a, b FROM baz_v1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM baz_v2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method was used to merge these tables.

(1) To use an union all the target tables, array type was flattened.

(2) In order to match the number of columns in the UNION ALL target tables, the number of columns is appended as much as the insufficient number of columns by
`LEFT JOIN (SELECT '' as y) ON FALSE` - [**reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363056/union-tables-with-different-schema-in-bigquery-standard-sql)

(3) ARRAY_AGG, STRUCT, GROUP BY were used to output the array result. - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243489/bigquery-aggregate-multiple-fields-into-array)

```
WITH `baz_v1` AS (
    SELECT
    [
        STRUCT(1 AS x),
        STRUCT(2 AS x)
    ] a,
    "one" b
), `baz_v2` AS (
    SELECT
    [
        STRUCT(3 AS x, 4 AS y),
        STRUCT(5 AS x, 6 AS y)
    ] a,
    "two" b
)

SELECT ARRAY_AGG (
    STRUCT(x, y) 
    ) as a,
    b
FROM (
    SELECT xy.x as x, xy.y as y, b
    FROM baz_v2, UNNEST(a) as xy
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x, y, b
    FROM (
        SELECT x.x as x, CAST(y as INT64) as y, b
        FROM baz_v1, UNNEST(a) as x
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT '' as y) ON FALSE
    ) 
)
GROUP BY b
```

with result)

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting, thanks. Do I understand correctly, that it assumes every value of `b` being unique?

Comment: @TobiasHermann. Yes. You are right. I'm really sorry, but there is a bug where b is assumed to be unique in the part that outputs the result as ARRAY

Comment: Thanks. That part was unclear in my original question (as Mikhail Berlyant pointed out). I've edited my question to show that `b` is not necessarily unique.